# Getting raster properties Using Mask File in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, spatial-analyst

I am trying to get raster properties using a Mask file for pixels that fall within mask, script will calculate that area statistics only.

Below is my script I am working on, but its showing an error

```py
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:\Annomaly_SPEI_12"
Mask = r"D:\Agro_Zone\Zone-1.shp"
rasterList = arcpy.ListRasters()

for raster in rasterList:
     rasterObj = arcpy.Raster(raster)
     print raster

     bands = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(Mask ,raster, "MEAN")
     print "MEAN VALUE: %s" %bands
```

Error Msg:

```
Property type: The input is not within the defined domain.
The value is not a member of MAXIMUM | MINIMUM | MEAN | STD | TOP | LEFT | RIGHT | BOTTOM | CELLSIZEX | CELLSIZEY | VALUETYPE | COLUMNCOUNT | ROWCOUNT | BANDCOUNT | ALLNODATA | ANYNODATA | SENSORNAME | PRODUCTNAME | ACQUSITIONDATE | SOURCETYPE | CLOUDCOVER | SUNAZIMUTH | SUNELEVATION | SENSORAZIMUTH | SENSORELEVATION | OFFNADIR | WAVELENGTH.
Failed to execute (GetRasterProperties).
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that the [10.5 documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/get-raster-properties.htm#GUID-918937B3-12A0-48BD-96E6-E6D30A6344E1) reflects that of 10.3 where the syntax for this tool is:

```
 GetRasterProperties_management (in_raster, {property_type}, {band_index})
```

For `property_type` (the second parameter), a value from `MAXIMUM | MINIMUM | MEAN | STD | TOP | LEFT | RIGHT | BOTTOM | CELLSIZEX | CELLSIZEY | VALUETYPE | COLUMNCOUNT | ROWCOUNT | BANDCOUNT | ALLNODATA | ANYNODATA | SENSORNAME | PRODUCTNAME | ACQUSITIONDATE | SOURCETYPE | CLOUDCOVER | SUNAZIMUTH | SUNELEVATION | SENSORAZIMUTH | SENSORELEVATION | OFFNADIR | WAVELENGTH` is expected.

You have provided a Raster object from `rasterList` instead.

Once you have addressed this I think you should look at the [Mask environment](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/mask.htm).  If GetRasterProperties honors that then you should have your solution.

Comment: PolyGeo, thank you. My query is how to assign a mask file. if i removed mask statement from my script then my script working fine. But i want to execute a mask file to get properties of raster for certain area. i am using Arc GIS 10.3 version

Comment: @SWAT it's what Polygeo says you need to set the ENVIRONMENT setting of arcpy and set the Mask, his link shows you how to do that.